# При создании бота столкнулся с ошибкой 'NoneType' object is not callable на строчке def start(message)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

```py
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('') # токен я вставил

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, ты написал мне /start')

bot.polling()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите полный `Traceback` (ошибку). Вы можете сделать это, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: как у вас назван файл в котором код из вашего вопроса?

Answer (score 0):

1. `pip uninstall telebot`
2. `pip install pytelegrambotapi`

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('') # токен я вставил

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, ты написал мне /start')

bot.polling()
```